# is this tree a valid binary search tree [1, 7, 11, 17, 21, 29, 74, 89, 91, 101, 132, 157]

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

for the mentioned below code in leetcode the output is mentioned as false

But i have used this javascript code to check validation and its returning true.

I want to understand whether my assumption of binary search tree is wrong or is there some end case i'm missing in my code pasted here?

need to understand how?

```
var arr = [1, 7, 11, 17, 21, 29, 74, 89, 91, 101, 132, 157];

function Node(data, left = null, right = null) {
  this.data = data;
  this.left = null;
  this.right = null;
}

let bstNode = createBSTRecurrsive(arr);
console.log(bstNode);
function createBSTRecurrsive(arr){
  if(arr.length == 0){
    return null;
  }
  let middle = parseInt(arr.length / 2);
  let root = new Node(arr[middle]);
  root.left = createBSTRecurrsive(arr.slice(0, middle));
  root.right = createBSTRecurrsive(arr.slice(middle + 1));
  return root;
}

isvalidBST(bstNode);
function isvalidBST(node){
  if(node == null){
    return true;
  }
  let stack = [];
  let temp = null;
  while(node != null || stack.length != 0){
    while(node != null){
      stack.push(node);
      node = node.left;
    }
    node = stack.pop();
    if(temp != null && node.data <= temp.data){
      console.log(node);
      console.log(temp);
      return false
    };
    temp = node;
    node = node.right;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You've given a sorted list, and code which converts it into a fairly balanced binary tree, then traverses the tree.

Comment: The function **isvalidBST** is failing for the mentioned input in leetcode i,e its returning true but as mentioned in leetcode it should have been false, trying to understand why the issue is happening, link for the problem is here [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/validate-binary-search-tree/). If the same code snippet is converted into other languages its working fine, meaning giving output as false

Comment: Their function accepts an array of numbers. Your function accepts a recursive `Node` structure. So you are not solving the problem. Now, constructing a BST as you do seems like a reasonable step in solving the actual problem. But you are misunderstanding how the array represents the BST. Notice that in their examples, the first member of the array is always the root. The way you are doing it, the median-index item of the array is the root, subroot, etc — which will always construct a valid BST if the array is ordered, as it is here!

Comment: It was a silly mistake, in the constructor definition they have used data for value part, but in my code i'm using val for storing value. `function TreeNode(val, left, right) {
  this.val = val === undefined ? 0 : val;
  this.left = left === undefined ? null : left;
  this.right = right === undefined ? null : right;
}`